# List comprehension of directories with multiple conditions

Tags: python

I have the following list comprehension:

```
dirs = [dir for dir in dirs if 'XXX_' in dir]
```

where the list comprehension is filtering out directories returned by an os.walk() that do not have 'XXX_' as part of the directory name. I have then been appending 'Supervisor' as a directory because I know that it will be included in any project that this script runs against.

This feels very hacky and I'm sure that there is a better way to include 'Supervisor' along with 'XXX_' in my filtering rather than filtering it out and then re-appending it.

The original segment of code is:

```
dirs = [os.path.basename(dir[0]) for dir in os.walk(os.getcwd())]
dirs = [dir for dir in dirs if 'XXX_' in dir]
dirs.append('Supervisor')
```

Can anyone recommend a cleaner solution?

Comment: you can do `dirs = [dir for dir in dirs if 'XXX_' in dir or 'Supervisor' in dir ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an or (exclusion) to your condition:

```
dirs = [dir for dir in dirs if 'XXX_' in dir or dir == 'Supervisor']
```

This will keep the dirs that either have `'XXX_'` in their name or are named `'Supervisor'`.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just about making a one-liner, i would `filter` the comprehension result:

```
dirs = filter(lambda d: 'XXX_' in d or 'Supervisor' == d, [os.path.basename(dir[0]) for dir in os.walk(os.getcwd())])
```

Note that this will return a generator, not a list. If you need a list, simply surround this statement with `list(...)`.